# Export Summary Statistics in Cytoscape 3.10

Tags: cytoscape

I want to export the summary statistics (e.g. density etc) from cytoscape. I can get them on the right hand side but there is no way to save them. The tutorials/manual speak of a 'Save Statistics button', however I cannot see such a button.

I get the stats by going to Tools -> Analyze Network. It asks if the network is directed, then once calculated the stats appear. How do I save them into a table? I would rather avoid manually copying them as I have loads of networks to compare over time.
Running in Linux.
Thanks,Phil

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, I couldn't find a way either, which I would consider a bug.  Can you please post a bug report?  We should be able to either put those values in the Network table (and you can download from there) or provide a way to download them as a table.  At bare minimum, you should *at least* be able to copy and paste them (which you also can't do).